# Error 500 Mono Apache Ubuntu with ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, apache2

```
Server Error in '/' Application
Access to the path "/var/www/Ubuntu/Bin" is denied.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/var/www/Ubuntu/Bin" is denied.
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.LoadPrecompilationInfo (System.String precomp_config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

I m Using Mono to run my ASP.NET C#,
All the code are working in my PC with Window XP SP3, IIS,
Unfortunately when i m trying to Upload all ASP.NET file to my Server with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, and this Error occurs.
I Have tried setting the Bin Folder to 777 permission, but still can't work.
Inside my Bin Folder is .DLL file to let ASP.NET `DirectMethod` call the function

This is my Bin Folder file's

`root@ubuntu:/var/www/Ubuntu/Bin# dir

App_Code.dll

App_Web_7userbmq.dll

Ext.Net.Utilities.dll

App_Web_7userbmq1.dll  Ext.Net.dll

Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

And this is my Apache2 Site Setting inside the path `/etc/apache2/sites-available/Ubuntu`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org
  ServerAdmin web-admin@example.org
  ServerAlias www.example.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/Ubuntu
  ErrorLog /var/www/Ubuntu/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/Ubuntu/logs/access.log combined

  MonoServerPath example.org "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2"
  MonoDebug example.org true
  MonoSetEnv example.org MONO_IOMAP=all
  MonoApplications example.org "/:/var/www/Ubuntu"
  <Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias example.org
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Update: on my PC i m using .NET 3.5, on Apache Mono are using 2.0. is this the problem?

Comment: Have you verified that the account running the application on the Apache machine has the access rights to the folders?

Comment: i m using `root` account...

Comment: I recommend you to use nginx, not apache

Comment: Are you using root or is Apache using root? Apache starts as root but immediately after switches to the account in the .conf file. You can check it with: ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'